# Decimal Declension II

Tags: склонение

This is a follow-up question to my earlier question about decimal declensions in colloquial speech. I understand that in everyday speech, native speakers bend the rules a little, and may not fully decline *long* decimal expressions ("pi equals 3.14159...").

But what about *short* decimals? For example, in everyday speech — or even in a radio or TV broadcast — how would one say "ot 1,4% do 5,7%"? Could you say the following?

> "ot odnoj [pause] chetyrekh procenta do pjati [pause] semi procenta"

Answer (score 2):

For short ones like that, having 1-3 digits after the coma (Russian uses a comma, not a dot in decimal fractions) we usually use the full form:

`от 1,4% дo 5,7%` is

`от одной целой [и] четырёх десятых процента до пяти целых [и] семи десятых процента`

Alternatively, rather colloquially, one can say that in such a way:

`от одного и четырёх процентов до пяти и семи процентов`

If there are 2 digits after the comma, we say it like this:

`от 1,45% дo 5,72%`

`от одной целой [и] сорока пяти сотых процента до пяти целых [и] семидесяти двух сотых процента`

Alternatively,

`от одного [и] сорока пяти процента до пяти [и] семидесяти двух процентов`

The point is, we can omit the word 'целая' (the feminine is used, because it is short for 'целая *часть*'), then the numeral becomes masculine agreeing with "процент", and we can omit the name of the place of the last digit (разряд), which are десятая for 1 digit after the comma, сотая for 2 digits after the comma, тысячная for 3 digits after the comma, and so on, they are also feminine, because it is short for 'десятая (сотая, etc.) *часть*':

```
1,1 одна целая [и] одна десятая
1,11 одна целая [и] одинадцать сотых
1,111 одна целая [и] сто одинадцать тысячных
1,1111 одна целая [и] тысяча сто одинадцать десятитысячных
```

But if there are several digits after the comma we never say them as separate digits, like in English, we tend to say them as a full number:

```
3,141 три целых [и] сто сорок одна тысячная / три [и] сто сорок одна
```

I really don't know what link or proof I can give, but I'm a linguist, a native speaker of Russian, and I studied at a mathematical school.

Comment: I agree that we drop word целая changing it to и and the phrase became "от одного и сорока пяти процента". I (and other people, too) also sometimes change order of words placing "процент" immediately after "одного": `от одного процента сорока пяти [сотых] до ...`

Comment: That's true. @farfareast

Answer (score 0):

In everyday speech we are omit 'percent' first word in range 1,4%-5,7%, like an other measure unit:

- 1,4% - 5,7% = 1,4-5,7%
- 2kg - 3kg = 2-3kg
- 50cm - 70cm = 50-70cm

Comma (decimal point) replaced by ...[pause] or 'и'. Also you may or may not to decline for cases integer and/or fractional part.

"от 1,4% до 5,7%" I'd pronounce like:

- от одного и четырёх до пяти и семи процента
  (от одного [процента] и четырёх [десятых] до пяти [целых] и семи [десятых] процента)
- от одной и четыре до пяти и семи процента
  (от одной [целой] и четыре [десятых] до пяти [целых] и семи [десятых] процента)
- от одного и четыре до пяти и семь процента
  (от одного [процента] и четыре [десятых] до пяти [целых] и семь [десятых] процента)
- от один и четыре до пять и семь процента
  (separate digits only, like in English)

"1,4-5,7%"
"один-и-четыре тире пять-и-семь процента" (separate digits with dash)

"1,2%"

- один и два процента (separate digits only)
- одна и две процента (omit words: одна [целая] и две [десятых] процента)
- один и две процента (mixed case: один [процент] и две [десятых] процента)

All this phases acceptable to colloquial speech, but not all to Radio and TV.